# TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined - REACTJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

I created a state where I am going to pass the value of the "ItemId"

```
constructor(){
    this.state = {
        item: ''
    }
}
```

this is where I declare the "ItemId"

```
renderItems = () => {
return ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'].map(ItemId => (
    <Menu.Item
        key={ItemId}
        value={ItemId}
        onClick={this.handleItem}
    >
        <Link>
            {ItemId}
        </Link>
    </Menu.Item>
  ));
}
```

this is where I'm getting the error

```
handleItem = e => {
  this.setState({
      item: e.target.value,
  })
  console.log('item: ', e.target.value)
}

render() {
  return(
     <Menu>
        {this.renderItems()}
     </Menu>
  );
}
```

Comment: What is your console.log logging?

Comment: What is `Menu.Item` ?

Comment: I'm getting the error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined" before it gets to console.log

Comment: the `event.target.value` use to get value from input change, in your case, you shuold pass the data from item that you want to handle to your `handleClick` function.

Comment: In handleItem, do this: e.persist(); then console.log(e); then check if e has a member of target

Comment: @dqlgnoleht i tried to other ways to make it work. Like changing the "value={ItemId}" to "data-div_id={ItemId}" and change the e.target.value to e.currentTarget.dataset.div_id but it is still not working

Comment: @johnmikelridzz I tried that and got the error "TypeError: e.persist is not a function"

Comment: @cmll: For further understanding, please let me know your used library, the `Menu.Item` is quite confused

Comment: @dqlgnoleht It's from the Ant Design Component equivalent of the list tag

Comment: Try it this way `item: e.target.getAttribute('value')`

Comment: `e` is not a click event, **Ant** components usually place the click event under `e.domEvent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using [`AntD Menu.Item`](https://ant.design/components/menu/) component. You must know that it doesn't pass back the event object as it is to the callback function on `onClick` event. Instead it passes an object with following keys: **`item, key, keyPath, domEvent`**

And since you want to set the item in state you can just use the `key` from the object

```
handleItem = ({key}) => {

    this.setState({
        item: key,
    })
    console.log('item: ', key)

}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you for your answer. I'm using AntD for less than a week so I kind of not know how it works. Appreciate you man!

Comment: The `onClick` should probably be added to the `Menu` component instead of adding it to every `Menu.Item` component.

Comment: Whenever you are stuck in such issues, I think its best to refer the docs and see if you can find out the mistake. It will help you learn more about the features and also provide you with detailed knowledge on the library

Comment: @Titus, yes that would probably be a better idea. However on menu, you need `onSelect` rather than onClick

Comment: There is an `onClick` for [`Menu`](https://ant.design/components/menu#Menu) and all the example on the doc page use that.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you're quite confused how to pass the `itemId` to the `handleItem` then you think this value should come from the `e.target.value`.

But for your case, you just need to pass it to the handle like I do, and it run as expected

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      item: ""
    };
  }

  handleItem = item => {
    this.setState({ item }, () => {
      console.log("item > ", this.state.item);
    });
  };

  renderItems = () => {
    return ["item1", "item2", "item3"].map(item => (
      <Menu.Item key={item} value={item} onClick={() => this.handleItem(item)}>
        <a>{item}</a>
      </Menu.Item>
    ));
  };

  render() {
    return <Menu>{this.renderItems()}</Menu>;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Side note: To make the `console.log` to check the state, I need write it inside the `setState` callback function because `setState` run asynchronously.